# OS selection screen not coming up on starting laptop HP N208-TX

Tags: 16.04, system-installation, wubi

I installed Ubuntu 16.04.2 using wubi installer whose download link I obtained from GitHub. After completing installation the selection screen which comes up for selecting which OS to use doesn't show. Instead the host operating system's(Windows 10) lock screen is encountered. Please solve this problem.

Comment: WUBI is no longer supported, so we are unlikely to help you with it. Please use a supported method of installing Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to duel boot, but after the install, the boot loader (the windows boot loader) doesn't see your Ubuntu install. If you need to work with 16.04, you can find the iso file [here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/xenial/). Otherwise, it's best just to go with either 18.10 or 18.04 because they are newer and will have a lot more up to date software included in their repositories and they are going to be supported further into the future than 16.04 is going to be.

[Ubuntu does have support for UEFI](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI), but if it gives you any trouble the easiest thing to do is to disable secure boot in BIOS settings. You can access that on HPs by pressing 'esc' key when booting which will give you the menu to get to the BIOS settings.

In Windows you can use a CD/DVD or a USB flash drive to boot off of for you installation. For USB flashing [UNetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/) is a good tool for making USB install drives. Or you should be able to burn the iso file to a disk from Windows File Explorer.

Once you've booted into the iso, all you need to do is select install and pick install along side Window. The Ubuntu install will have you pick how much hard drive space you want to dedicate to Ubuntu. After the installation you should be given an option to either boot into Windows or Ubuntu when you boot the computer.